# Ansible nested condition

Tags: ansible

How can I achieve "nested when" (nested if) in Ansible task?

For example,
I want to print item.name if item.name is defined and equals to "hello world".

```
- name: display foo if foo.name equals to "hello world"
  debug:
      var: item
  when item.name is defined and item.name == "hello world"
  with_items:
  - {'name': 'hello world'}
  - {'age': 14}
  - {'name': 'john'}
```

However, if foo.name is not defined, it fails and reports item.name is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You can test if the field is available:

```yaml
when: "'name' in item and item.name == 'hello world'"
```

You can also protect with a `default`:

```yaml
when: "item.name | default(None) and item.name == 'hello world'"
```

BTW, it's possible to express AND tests on different lines (but not sure it's good in that case because don't know if it use lazy evaluation, e.g. stop evaluating at first `False`):

```yaml
 when:
   - "'name' in item"
   - "item.name == 'hello world'"
```

`with_items` syntax is deprecated for the `loop` syntax.

If possible, better to filter the input:

```yaml
- name: display foo if foo.name equals to "hello world"
  debug:
      var: item
  loop: "{{ input_list | selectattr('name', 'defined') | selectattr('name', 'equalto', 'hello world') }}"
```

(edit: added `selectattr('name', 'defined')` to avoid error indicated by @Vladimir Botka)

Comment: Where does the test ``equalsto`` come from?

Comment: It's a built-in test in Jinja : https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-tests.eq (without typo it's `equalto`, or `eq` or `==`)

Comment: And `selectattr` is a built-in filter: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr

Answer (score 1):

Given the list

```yaml
l1:
  - name: hello world
  - age: 14
  - name: john
```

---

Q: ***"Print `item.name` if `item.name` is defined and equals to `hello world`."***

A: Use [*json_query*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries). This filter ignores missing attributes. For example,

```yaml
l2: "{{ l1|json_query('[?name == `hello world`]') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
l2:
  - name: hello world
```

---

Notes

- Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    l1:
      - name: hello world
      - age: 14
      - name: john
    l2: "{{ l1|json_query('[?name == `hello world`]') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ l2 }}"
```

- It is not possible to use *selectattr*. The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ l1|selectattr('name', 'eq', 'hello world') }}"
```

fails

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'name'
```